# no data in newrelic UI after RecordCustomEvent RecordCustomMetric

Tags: go, newrelic

I am using [newrelic go-agent](https://github.com/newrelic/go-agent/blob/master/examples/short-lived-process/main.go#L35) to send custom data

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/newrelic/go-agent"
)

func main() {
    cfg := newrelic.NewConfig("my-golang-app", mustGetEnv("NEWRELIC_LICENSE_KEY"))
    cfg.Logger = newrelic.NewDebugLogger(os.Stdout)
    app, err := newrelic.NewApplication(cfg)
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Wait for the application to connect.
    if err := app.WaitForConnection(5 * time.Second); nil != err {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Do the tasks at hand.  Perhaps record them using transactions and/or
    // custom events.
    tasks := []string{"white", "black", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow"}
    for _, task := range tasks {
        txn := app.StartTransaction("task", nil, nil)
        if err := txn.NoticeError(fmt.Errorf("fake error")); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        if err := txn.End(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if err := app.RecordCustomEvent("task", map[string]interface{}{
            "color": task,
        }); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        for i := 0; i <= 1000; i++ {
            if err := app.RecordCustomMetric("my_metric", float64(rand.Intn(1000))); err != nil {
                log.Printf("%+v", err)
            }
        }
    }
    log.Println("ok")
    // Shut down the application to flush data to New Relic.
    app.Shutdown(10 * time.Second)
    log.Println("good")
}

func mustGetEnv(key string) string {
    if val := os.Getenv(key); "" != val {
        return val
    }
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("environment variable %s unset", key))
}
```

It works perfectly without any error.

I can see my transaction with name `task` in newrelic UI and this error
`txn.NoticeError(fmt.Errorf("fake error"))` is shown as well.

But I can't find `color` of my custom event:

```
app.RecordCustomEvent("task", map[string]interface{}{
            "color": task,
        }
```

and my custom metric

```
app.RecordCustomMetric("my_metric", float64(rand.Intn(1000)))
```

there

Comment: Have you tried removing panic during fake error?

Comment: @whitespace that panic is never been thrown so far, the program works up until `log.Println("good")` without errors